# Block google maps from loading until user agrees to cookies with Elementor

Tags: cookies, google

So im in the middle of doing my privacy policy with my lawyer and he has mentioned that one of the more important things to be GDPR compliant is that if a user denies cookies from being allowed (besides functional), google maps should not load. He sent me a link to [borlabs.io](http://borlabs.io) which supposedly has a good way of blocking things - but since this is an elementary widget, I didn't find a way to get it working.

Do you have any suggestions on how to block google maps before cookies are accepted? Any plugins that you use to help with the GDPR? 
Oh, and to make things more complex - I am using a custom post type with ACF; and on each of those posts is the maps widget via an Elementor template.

I appreciate any help & Advice here,

Cheers,

S

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.